# Сохранение выбранных пунктов списка множественного выбора в БД

Tags: php, mysql, sql

В [html](/questions/tagged/html) форме есть список множественного выбора. Нужно сделать так, чтобы выбранные пункты списка отправлялись в одно поле БД, через запятую.

```
if ($_POST){
    $abon_login = $_POST['login'];
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
    $sending = $_POST['sending']; 
    $pay = $_POST['pay']; 
    $orders = $_POST['orders'];
    $news = $_POST['news'];
    $other = $_POST['other'];

    $table = $system_site_prefix . 'erps_services_sms'; 
    database_insert("INSERT INTO `$table` VALUES ('$index', '$abon_login', '$telephone', 
        '".implode(",", $sending)."', '$pay', '$orders', '$news', '$other')");
```

Выбранные пункты списка должны заноситься в переменную [sending](/questions/tagged/sending), а после - в базу. Попробовал с помощью функции [implode](/questions/tagged/implode) - не вышло. Подскажите пожалуйста, как лучше это сделать.

Comment: Лучше так не делать, в принципе, значения через запятую в поле реляционной БД ведут к невозможности нормального поиска по полю и куче всяких сюрпризов. Кроме того подставлять значения принятых откуда либо переменных непосредственно в текст запроса - верный путь в взлому вашего сайта, sql-инъекция делается на раз-два

Comment: Каким образом тогда поступить? Имеете в виду, выбранные пункты списка лучше вообще не заносить в одно поле таблицы? Просто о защите вопрос пока не стоит, мне бы разобраться в конкретно в этой проблеме.

Comment: Конечно зависит от того что это за поле. Если его потом просматривает непосредственно сам человек, никакого поиска по нему и никаких связанных таблиц нет - можно конечно через запятую. Но если есть связанная таблица (да хоть справочник возможных значений) или если будет поиск - создается отдельная таблица где каждое из значений отдельной строкой лежит

Comment: Никакого поиска и связанных таблиц не будет, по крайней мере, в ближайшее время. Подскажите пожалуйста каким образом я могу занести несколько пунктов списка в одно поле БД.

Comment: Ну оно выглядит нормально если у вас в той переменной действительно массив.... вы бы получающийся запрос распечатали и посмотрели что там на самом деле формируется ...

Comment: Просто не совсем понимаю как занести выбранные пункты в массив

Comment: Кстати, всегда в insert явно перечисляйте колонки в которые идет вставка `insert into table(col1, col2, col3, ) values(...)` во первых сами будете видеть что не ошиблись с порядком значений. Во вторых если списка колонок нет, если в будущем добавите к таблице колонку, даже необязательную,  не используемую в данном insert, вам придется не забыть разыскать этот запрос в программе и добавить в него что то ...

Comment: Хорошо, больше спасибо за полезные советы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил. В [html](/questions/tagged/html) у тега [select](/questions/tagged/select) в атрибуте [name](/questions/tagged/name) нужно было после имени дописать квадратные скобки,

```
<select multiple name="sending[]">
```

чтобы [php](/questions/tagged/php) обращался с [sending](/questions/tagged/sending) как с массивом

Answer (score 1):

Теоретически, все должно нормально работать. Возможно в числе элементов массива $sending есть ошибочные.

Хорошо бы временно заменить ваш database_insert на

```
if(!$ins=mysql_query("INSERT INTO....")){
    echo mysql_error() . " " . __LINE__ . "<br>";
}
```

и посмотреть, что покажет ошибка mysql. Скорей всего там и выяснится проблема

Comment: Заменил как вы сказали - никаких ошибок, данные добавились в базу. Может проблема в том, что у меня $sending не массив, поэтому в базу заносится только один выбранный пункт списка. Как сделать $sending массивом?

Comment: Если sending выбирается select'ом в форме добавления, то в тег <select...> надо добавить multiple, если не select'ом, то имя input'а должно быть name="inputname[]"

Comment: Сначала нашел ответ, потом увидел ваш комментарий. Большое спасибо за помощь.